# java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException:Certificate expired at Thu Oct 20 19:59:59EDT 2022 (compared to Wed Jan04 17:53:35EST 2023) for Android

Tags: android, ssl, post, https, java-security

So a bit of back story. This error code is only coming up on an app that was created around 2018 or so and was working all the way up until a couple months back. This error pops up when I am making a HTTPS POST call (So a login into the API). There is also an iOS version of the app and it is working normally. Both iOS and Android are pointing to the same endpoint too.

Back to Android. In the logs, it shows that the login was successful, but I won't get passed the login screen because of that said error. I was recreating the app and set up the login component of the app and it showed in the logs that I logged into the API successfully there as well. So the issue is only coming up from this particular version of the app.

Here's the error code:

```
W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLUtils.toSSLHandshakeException(SSLUtils.java:362)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.convertException(ConscryptEngine.java:1134)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(ConscryptEngine.java:1089)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:876)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:747)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:712)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:849)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.access$100(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:722)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:238)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:217)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:379)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:337)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:209)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:188)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:45)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12267)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12267)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromObservable.subscribeActual(FlowableFromObservable.java:29)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableOnBackpressureLatest.subscribeActual(FlowableOnBackpressureLatest.java:32)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap.subscribeActual(FlowableFlatMap.java:53)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap.subscribeActual(FlowableMap.java:37)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableOnErrorNext$OnErrorNextSubscriber.onError(FlowableOnErrorNext.java:115)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleToFlowable$SingleToFlowableObserver.onError(SingleToFlowable.java:67)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleCreate$Emitter.tryOnError(SingleCreate.java:94)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleCreate$Emitter.onError(SingleCreate.java:80)
W/System.err:     at com.parabit.parabeacon.app.demo.data_section.LocalStorage.lambda$getDeviceIdInfo$15(LocalStorage.java:236)
W/System.err:     at com.parabit.parabeacon.app.demo.data_section.LocalStorage$$ExternalSyntheticLambda9.subscribe(Unknown Source:2)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleCreate.subscribeActual(SingleCreate.java:39)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleToFlowable.subscribeActual(SingleToFlowable.java:37)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableOnErrorNext.subscribeActual(FlowableOnErrorNext.java:40)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap.subscribeActual(FlowableFlatMap.java:53)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.onNext(FlowableFlatMap.java:163)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromArray$ArraySubscription.slowPath(FlowableFromArray.java:162)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromArray$BaseArraySubscription.request(FlowableFromArray.java:90)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.onSubscribe(FlowableFlatMap.java:117)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromArray.subscribeActual(FlowableFromArray.java:38)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap.subscribeActual(FlowableFlatMap.java:53)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:82)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Chain validation failed
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:724)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:554)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:575)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:620)
I/chatty: uid=10207(com.parabit.parabeacon.app.demo) identical 1 line
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:620)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:510)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:428)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:356)
W/System.err:     at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
W/System.err:     at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:90)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$2.checkServerTrusted(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:161)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:250)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptEngine.java:1644)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.ENGINE_SSL_read_direct(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.readDirectByteBuffer(NativeSsl.java:568)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextDataDirect(ConscryptEngine.java:1095)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(ConscryptEngine.java:1079)
W/System.err:   ... 70 more
W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
W/System.err:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:135)
W/System.err:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:222)
W/System.err:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:140)
W/System.err:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:79)
W/System.err:     at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:301)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:720)
W/System.err:   ... 87 more
W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: Certificate expired at Thu Oct 20 19:59:59 EDT 2022 (compared to Wed Jan 04 17:53:35 EST 2023) //<- Here's the real issue
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate.checkValidity(OpenSSLX509Certificate.java:269)
W/System.err:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifyTimestamp(BasicChecker.java:194)
W/System.err:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(BasicChecker.java:144)
W/System.err:     at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125)
W/System.err:   ... 92 more
```

I've been searching all day for a solution but couldn't find anything on this error that was tangible. Any ideas or solutions is appreciated. Thank you. If you need anymore info, please let me know.

P.S. The Android apps were built on Android Studio.

Comment: Your Web server's SSL certificate would appear to have expired. "was working all the way up until a couple months back" -- probably it was working up until October 20, 2022.

Comment: "I've been searching all day for a solution" As the error is clearly showing, the certificate has expired. So the solution is simply to replace that now useless certificate with a new one not expired. As such your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, it is just a matter of handling certificates properly and renewing them, which is system administration.

Comment: How will I go about renewing the certificate? @Patrick Mevzek

Comment: The same way you did get that first certificate, just redo the procedure.

Comment: I didn't create the project, I'm just inheriting it. So I'm not sure how to go about updating the certificate. Are there specific ways of updating the certificate for different projects? @Patrick Mevzek

Comment: "Are there specific ways of updating the certificate for different projects?" There is about 1 million different ways to do things, or so, so no generic answer. It starts with which CA you are using. If Lets'Encrypt then look at certbot. If not, and not finding anything on your side, try to ask the CA for help. Or just redo everything with Let's Encrypt. Certificates, like domain names, expire. Any installation requiring them should fully document how to renew them, and even better if this is automated fully.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I really appreciate it. @Patrick Mevzek